# Libraries/frameworks for an open source web based business process modeler

Tags: database, visio, bpmn

We are looking to build an open source modern web/HTML5 based business process modeler for our master's project. The core design idea is making something simple – like Visio with only a few stencil/figure sets but with a database, such as mysql or postgress, enabling the same objects to be reused and have relationships, and descriptions and documents attached to the various objects/stencils.

We are not going to try to build something that models processes to the level of detail allowing it to be executable, such as jBPM, Activiti and Camunda. We are hoping to build something clean and simple.

Any suggestions/thoughts on frameworks/libraries/languages that could be useful in developing this and why?

Comment: Not an answer, but: you might want to have a look at what http://bpmn.io/ is already doing in that direction. It is open sourced (see https://github.com/bpmn-io), so you might want to offer contributions instead of building something new from scratch? In any case, I wish you all the best!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about bpmn.io. It looks like a great basis for front end, but I guess it won't evolve into supporting a database etc.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer either, but if I were you I would give a try to angularJS. With your own AngularJS library you would be able to build the front end with a nice layout - and it would be quite easily linked to a backend database (for instance http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp).

some framework to consider for modeling: http://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/